# Quicksort where the pivot is chosen randomly

Tags: structure, quicksort

I have the following question:

```
Let A=[84,33,72,60,22,63] be an array of numbers. 
We want to sort A using Quicksort where the pivot is chosen randomly.
At the end of the **first iteration** it might be that A will be?
1.A=[63,33,72,60,84,22]
2.A=[84,33,72,60,22,63]
3.A=[22,33,72,60,84,63]
```

I would love an explanation, I can not understand why I can not get to one of the answers shown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does an iteration do? You take the pivot and move all the lesser numbers before it and greater after it. Try to figure out what the pivot might have been to get those answers. If there isn't a valid option, then that answer most likely isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 6 numbers in this array hence if you randomly pick a pivot point the first iteration might have 6 possible results. For example if 84 is picked at random the first iteration would result in
A = [33,72,60,22,63,**84**]
As you can see 84 was the biggest number in the list so all the entries on the right was moved to the left during the search.